# Normal and @2x sizes for all resources?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

Should all my app image resources have both normal size and @2x size? Or do I just need to provide this for launch image, icon image and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you want to supply every resource with normal and 2x assets. Otherwise other image assets will look blocky under retina.

Comment: Sir, could u plz elaborate. If my deployment target is iOS 7. I know all the devices will be retina. Do I still need normal size images or only @2x?

Comment: iOS 7 works on an iPad 2, so that's one non-retina device that your app could run on.

Comment: Yes, u r right. In my case I'm iPhone only. I don't want to make my app size bigger without any reason. Is there any other reason for using normal images?

Comment: Then no, not that I know of.

Comment: I thought for iOS7 and up, one had to provide only @2x images, because iOS7 will scale them down automatically for non-retina displays. Is this right, or does one still have to provide low res images additionally?